# AWS Aurora cluster: strong or eventual consistency?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a Aurora PostgresSQL cluster with read replicas.
I want to find out (preferably in AWS docs) if it gives strong consistency for reads from RO replicas after writes or is it "eventually consistent" meaning that RO replicas can return stale data during ongoing replication?

Unfortunately, this is not super clear from the documentation.
What I have found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Replication.html) is:

```
As a result, all Aurora Replicas return the same data for query results with minimal replica lag. 
This lag is usually much less than 100 milliseconds after the primary instance has written an update.
```

However, I am not sure how to interpret this - does it return always the same data at a cost of higher latency with an added replication lag or can it return stale data during the replication?

Also, I am not sure if it depends on the underlying DB engine (Postgres in my case).

Comment: Update: Since Amazon Aurora Replicas share the same data volume as the primary instance in the same AWS Region, there is virtually no replication lag. We typically observe lag times in the tens of milliseconds.
Link: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/#How_far_behind_the_primary_will_my_replicas_be.3F

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is **asynchronous** replication as written in the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/). This means that Aurora replicas can return old data even though the new one has already been written in the writer instance.

Comment: True. Also to mention they write that "Amazon Aurora Replicas share the same data volume as the primary instance in the same AWS Region, there is virtually no replication lag. We typically observe lag times in the 10s of milliseconds."

Answer (score 4):

As already said, data from the reader node is considered as "eventually consistent" even though the reader node(s) and the R/W node both share the same managed storage.
The reason for this eventual consistency is because the propagation of WAL logs to the buffer pool of the reader node(s) is asynchronous. I.e. the writer node doesn't wait for the reader node(s) to confirm that it has applied the WAL logs to its buffer pool before acknowledging the transaction  to the client app. **But this "eventual consistency" will only appear if the reader node happened to have data affected by those WAL logs in its buffer pool. Otherwise the reader node will read from the managed storage, which is always strongly consistent.**

[After some milliseconds](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/#What_kind_of_replicas_does_Aurora_support.3F), the reader nodes' buffer pool will anyway be updated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aurora's Redo/WAL are sent from the primary instance to storage volumes for every data modification. This storage volume is shared by the primary and standby instances. Once storage volume persists these changes across 2 AZs (4/6 copies), acknowledgement is sent to application. So every write is always durably persisted in storage across 2 AZs before moving ahead.

Salient point here is that the standby node needs to run a local crash recovery before being promoted to align its in-memory state based on the shared storage volume.

This is because, if there is a database page in the standby instance's buffer pool (cache) that has been changed by the primary and in the storage, then there should be a process to update it in standby's cache. If application will read such pages from the standby instance before its cache is updated, then the application will read stale data (replica lag).