# Is there any replication lag for aws Aurora cluster or can we ever read the stale data due to replication lag?

Tags: replication, amazon-aurora

Similar question but did not clear my doubt: [AWS Aurora cluster: strong or eventual consistency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027942/aws-aurora-cluster-strong-or-eventual-consistency) 
According to aws doumentation, replication is done asychronously and there could be a replication lag of around 10th of miliseconds.
But aurora uses qouroms for read and write. There are 6 copies of data and write is aknowledged only when data is written to 4 storage nodes and read is done from 3 storage nodes. So there will always be one storage node which will have latest data.
Article: [AWS Aurora cluster: strong or eventual consistency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027942/aws-aurora-cluster-strong-or-eventual-consistency)
So I have following questions:

1. What is meaning of replication lag in Aurora Mysql, since stale data can never be read?
2. Will there be ever any chance of data loss during failover due to replication lag? (when primary instance crashes due to some reason and replica takes over as primary instance)

Please note that all instnaces are on same region and there is single master db instance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. The meaning of the Replication lag is: "For an Aurora replica, the amount of lag when replicating updates from the primary instance." [Aurora metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.AuroraMySQL.Monitoring.Metrics.html)
2. The failover is handled automatically by AWS and the promotion of a replica to primary instance takes around 30 seconds. They state that no data will be lost - [faqs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/). Therefore, my assumption is that while there is a chance for that to happen (as for everything :) ), it is very small and shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this answer there is replication delay, as well as write delay.

Creating databases and modifying the structure of the databases seems to have more delay than inserting and updating data.

As for the amount of delay time this seems to vary from a few seconds to a minute or two.

(I am using Aurora Serverless, so not sure if its different with other types)